# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE al realizar múltiples acciones

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, mysqli

Tengo una pagina al estilo de spotify, básicamente reproduce canciones, cuando la probaba en localhost funcionaba perfecto, pero en el servidor tiene un problema, cuando me pongo a reproducir muchas canciones seguidas casi sin darle tiempo a que comiencen, la pagina deja de funcionar y envía el error:

Esta página no funciona

www.dominio.com no ha enviado ningún dato.

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

El hosting no parece ser ya que no marca ningún error, pero a su vez tampoco recibo ninguno error log de PHP.

La pagina vuelve a funcionar automáticamente unos segundos después del error, pero mientras no funciona, no se puede entrar desde ningún dispositivo (Si hago el error en la PC y intento entrar en el celular, no funciona en ninguno, por lo tanto chrome no debe ser el problema)
No tengo mucha experiencia, así que no tengo la idea de cual podría ser el error.

Para el desarrollo de usa html, css, ajax, mysqli y js

Código que reproduce las canciones:

```
    <?php
    $songIdArray = $album->getSongIds();

    $i = 1;
    foreach($songIdArray as $songId) {

        $albumSong = new Song($con, $songId);
        $albumArtist = $albumSong->getArtist();

        echo "<li class='tracklistRow'>
                <div class='trackCount'>
                    <img class='play' src='assets/images/icons/play-white.png' onclick='setTrack(\"" . $albumSong->getId() . "\", tempPlaylist, true)'>
                    <span class='trackNumber'>$i</span>
                </div>


                <div class='trackInfo'>
                    <span class='trackName'>" .  $albumSong->getTitle() . "</span>
                    <span class='artistName'>" . $albumArtist->getName() . "</span>
                </div>

                <div class='trackOptions'>
                    <input type='hidden' class='songId' value='" . $albumSong->getId() . "'>
                    <img class='optionsButton' src='assets/images/icons/more.png' onclick='showOptionsMenu(this)'>
                </div>

                <div class='trackDuration'>
                    <span class='duration'>" . $albumSong->getDuration() . "</span>
                </div>


            </li>";

        $i = $i + 1;
    }

    ?>

    <script>
        var tempSongIds = '<?php echo json_encode($songIdArray); ?>';
        tempPlaylist = JSON.parse(tempSongIds);
    </script>






    function playSong() {

        if(audioElement.audio.currentTime == 0) {
            $.post("includes/handlers/ajax/updatePlays.php", { songId: audioElement.currentlyPlaying.id });
        }

        $(".controlButton.play").hide();
        $(".controlButton.pause").show();
        audioElement.play();
    }
```

Comment: [Mira este hilo](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome-es/IafpyX5abJM/oXXsBpuvuMgJ) , puede que sea un problema propio de tu equipo o entorno de red (Firewall u otro bloqueo). Si puedes probar desde otra red/equipo (tú mismo o pidiendo a alguien de confianza que esté en otro sitio que haga pruebas) se podría confirmar o descartar esa posibilidad.

Comment: Ya probé con el 4G del celular y pasa lo mismo